# After Effects spectrum on path has gabs on angles

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm working on a project where I have a spectrum running along a path in the form of a pentagon. I wanted to use this to generate 2 lines in the rough form of a pentagon but [reacting to the music in the project:

[image]

As you can see around the angle the lines disconnect because of how the angles work. I'd like to have them connect though. Is there a way to connect these lines?